# Is it as easy as buying 1BTC and leaving it in a wallet? is there anything else to "Bitcoin investment"?

Tags: security, investing

Just as title says, I always hear about BTC lately and want to get in on it, or is it too late?

Comment: You've asked different questions in title and body.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, holding them in your wallet is pretty much the thing.

Also, remember to backup and [secure your wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Securing_your_wallet).

It may be hard to win the game, but it's very easy to lose it with a hard drive failure.

Comment: There is NO higher authority to turn to to help you recover misplaced bitcoins.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, investing in Bitcoin basically means buying bitcoins and holding them in your Bitcoin wallet.

You can still invest, it's not too late. But nobody knows if you'll lose everything or make a profit.

Answer (score 0):

Would you really consider purchasing 1 BTC a valid investment? That's like purchasing 1 share of everything on the NYSE. In the end you won't earn as much as you would want to. Furthermore, you have to be a bit more interested in the success of the BTC to justify investment.

To answer the question, BTC investment is as easy as leaving 1 BTC in a wallet. The BTC will probably reach a higher value but that speculative because the entire economy is an experiment that has never been carried out in practice. This is why it is a volatile currency.

Mining is not a viable way to invest since the difficulty of successfully mining BTC has gone way up due to tech advances in hashing and BTCs increased popularity.

Comment: Considering there are going to be 7 billion people having to divide 21 million bitcoin... I'd say 1BTC is a pretty good investment... and fairly low risk in absolute terms. (saying this 1 hour after it dropped from 900 to 600 USD...)

Comment: @Jannes: This assumes, of course, that anywhere near 7 billion people are actually going to want any of those 21 million bitcoins.  That's by no means a given.